# In AUTOSAR E2E Profile1, CAN the counter max value be 0xF?

Tags: autosar, e2e

In AUTOSAR E2E Profile1, the counter max value is fixed as 0x0E. But what if we want to change it to 0xF? Any side effect? is there any consideration to skip the 0xF in the original AUTOSAR standard?

I checked the AUTOSAR_SWS_E2ELibrary.pdf, it only says 0xF is a invalid value to be skipped. But why is it an invalid value? waht's the consequences if we not skip the 0xF?
One of my customer insist to use the 0xF unless we can show them the side effects.

Answer (score 0):

The value 0x0F is meant as "invalid value", which means, even though the message was transmitted (by Com out of its message buffer initialized at Com_Init()), it might be default inital data, and SWC was not running, and therefore not updating the data. That can be found out by the receiver, because of the invalid.

Changing this and using 0x0F as valid value means, you are violating the standardized E2E Profile1. If the E2E Profile1 is specified in the SystemDescription to be used, every communication partner does rely on E2E Profile1 as specified in AUTOSAR, *not* your "we use 0xF as valid" implementation and will fail.

Not sure, why your customer relies on 0x0F being a valid value for E2E Profile1. Tell him, this violates AUTOSAR.